# Admin Menu doesn't slide out and configuration menue doesn't open. Also buttons not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, optimization, js-translation

Preconditions (*)

1. Magento 2.3.1
2. Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
3. PHP 7.2.17

Working in dev environment and and enabled few optimization parameters which made admin panel inaccessible and buttons were don't appear correct with proper text , appears shrinked.
Admin panels don't draw out even if does then none of the buttons registers a click and hence I'm not able to change the configurations back.
Steps to reproduce (*)

I was trying to speed up my webstore but it created a havoc.

```
1.Enable JS minify/merge/bundling
2.Enable CSS minify/merging
3.Enable Html minify
4.Enable Embedded Translation Mode for JS translation strategy.
```

Tried changing back

```
1.Enable JS minify/merge/bundling
2.Enable CSS minify/merging
3.Enable Html minify.
```

but no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Change back JS translation strategy from embedded to dictionary. As i18n js errors were observed when inspection was done in browser.

> stores->configuration0->advanced->developer->js translation strategy.